# XStream-like XML serialization for Jython objects?

Tags: serialization, xml-serialization, jython

Jython is great for creating custom data structures on need basis, but how to store their instances? Apparently it's possible to do it via `java.io.Serializable`, but `ObjectStreams` are not human readable; I would prefer XML.

I naïvely tried [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to serialize a simple object created in Jython and translated to Java with `PyObject`'s `__tojava__` method, but the result was, expectedly, pretty much gibberish because of XStream's heavy use of reflection (it finds all Jython's internals) - and deserialization doesn't work (maybe because of Jython's dynamically loaded proxy classes or some other implementation details that I'm really not familiar with.)

Is there anything like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) for Jython objects - perhaps a Jython library?

Comment: If it includes the useful bits as well, perhaps just applying a filter would work. XStream is very configurable although half of it seems like magic until you kick it a few times.

Comment: Yes, there are useful bits as well. But I'm pretty sure that each data structure would require a slightly different filter, so there should also be some clever way to construct filters on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Jython is not that ideal for on need data *structure* creation although it's great for custom data *processing*. I ended up using DynaBeans from [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) to create the data structures. They play with XStream and Jython just fine.